# Use same Gradle Version as what Android Studio does in Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

I am trying to understand and use Jenkins for Android development, one thing I always try to avoid is to have a tons of different Gradle version on my working space so all of projects I am working on shares same Gradle version specified at `gradle-wrapper.properties` while the folder where Gradle is stored in

```
C:\Users\USER_NAME\.gradle\wrapper\dists
```

[image]

Whenever there is a new Gradle version that Android Studio suggest to migrate on, I always delete previous version and update all apps Gradle version manually to the latest one before opening them again so it won't download again the old version.

Now I wanted to point Jenkins to use this path as well to avoid duplicate, minimize available disk consumption and have a clean environment. So far this is what I did in Jenkins trying to do same approach.

[image]

This however does not work as when I tried to build my app, it downloads another similar version of Gradle in a different folder path.

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\wrapper\dists
```

[image]

[image]

My question is how can I achieved Jenkins to use same Gradle as Android Studio does?
Is it doable?

Comment: `gradle-wrapper.properties` must be in folder `$project/gradle/wrapper`

Answer (score 0):

Already manage to do this by specifying Gradle home at
**Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Scroll down to Global Properties and check Environment Variables**

then add your Gradle path like shown in the image.

[image]